# Python read file by line separate by tab then insert into tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, split, treeview, readfile

I am attempting to create a treeview in tkinter that is populated with data from a txt file. This file has a few lines and on each line there is an article title, a single tab, and then an article number matching the title. I am attempting to read all lines in the file and split by tab so that I can insert the titles and article numbers into their respective columns in a treeview made with Tkinter. The treeview only has two columns for title and article number. Obviously I need the title and numbers to match up in the treeview even if the treeview is filtered or rearranged. How would I do this?

I figured something like this would at least get me two lists with the correct values:

```
filename = "ArtIDs.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as readfile:    
   types = (line.split("\t") for line in readfile)
   xys = ((type[1], type[2]) for type in types)
   for x, y in xys:
      print(x,y)
```

But I keep getting a "list index out of range" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be started from 0

try:

```
filename = "ArtIDs.txt"  
with open(filename, "r") as readfile:      
    types = (line.split("\t") for line in readfile)  
    xys = ((type[0], type[1]) for type in types)  
    for x, y in xys:  
        print(x,y)
```

please try this one, may be it help:

```
main = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(main)
frame.grid()
tree = ttk.Treeview(main, columns=('1', '2'))
tree.grid(column=0, sticky='N' + 'S' + 'E' + 'W')
n = 1
with open(filename, "r") as readfile:
    types = (line.split("\t") for line in readfile)
    xys = ((type[0], type[1]) for type in types)
    for x, y in xys:
       tree.insert("", n, values=(x, y))
       n+=1

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That does print the correct values for the two lists. But how do I insert 'each line' into the treeview columns? I can do 

"self.tree.insert('', '0', values=(x,y))"

But it only shows the very last entry in the first row of the treeview.

Comment: Hey thanks again! The treeview is now populating with both title and article # for the entire list. I was still getting an unbound error from the 'n+=1' line. But that is resolved after setting the variable properly. I have this organized into classes and functions. So it was needed.